# Send data to com port virtually

Tags: windows, serial-communication

I'm writing a Mathlab programe for get input from a serial port.

```
serPort = serial('COM5','BaudRate', 57600);
fopen(serPort);
.....
```

Now i want to check this programe with virtual com port(COM5) and sent data to the port virtually. 
Can someone suggest a software to do this. 
(Everything is in the same computer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try VirtualBox, it creates a virtual machine in which you can virtualize the com port (to a file if you want).